# Use google drive with multiple Drives?

Tags: google-drive

I have an SSD on which I store my data, where my Google Drive folder is too. But there are some files I want to access sometimes, just rarely, but that take up too much space. I would like to move them to my HDD, but I can't seem to find a way to make it so two Google Drive folders are synced.

Comment: Does your google drive client follow links? What client is it, and what's your OS? Try a link in the google drive folder pointing to the file in another location.

Comment: @Xen2050 Windows 10, and no, they get uploaded as .lnk files

Comment: I thought it might not support links yet (has been a feature request since at least 2012, probably since it's beginning). Could keep the files in google drive's folder and use a link somewhere else, but that wouldn't shrink google drive's folder... I think I have an answer to exclude files from syncing to your local folder

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sync some folders in Google Drive, and delete them from your local synced folder but still keep a cloud copy on Google Drive, you could follow [this webapps answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59265/83107) and:

> Simply right-click the Google Drive app. Check "Only sync some folders to this computer". Then check the folders that you want to sync. Files that are in unchecked folders will not be synced. After that, you can delete your local copies and the files in the cloud will be unaffected.
>
> (To prevent accidentally losing files, I would create the folder in the Google Drive interface first, and leave it empty. Then use the Google Drive app to exclude that folder from syncing. Then upload the photo files to the folder on the web.)
>
> * Note: This may only work for top-level folders